# Reference another internal module implicitly in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have

> List.ts:

```
module Helper {
   export class List{

   }
}
```

> Parser.ts:

```
module Helper {
   export class Parser {
   }
}
```

Now I have another module, and every time I want to use "List", I need to say Helper.List. Is it possible to just say something like:

```
import Helper;

module Data {
    export interface DataRepository {
        getRange() : List<string>;
    }
}
```

So that every time I want to use `List`, I can just type `List` instead of `List.Helper`? I know you can do:

```
import List = Helper.List;
```

But is something like

```
import * from Helper;
```

possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only possible when you use [external modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html) (which are recommended). However, you can do the following:

```
module Helper {
   export class List<T> {

   }
}

module Helper {
   export class Parser {
   }
}

module Data {
    export interface DataRepository {
        getRange() : Helper.List<string>;
    }
}
```

Or

```
module Data {
    type StringList = Helper.List<string>;
    export interface DataRepository {
        getRange() : StringList;
    }
}
```